# Change x-axis in violin plot in R

Tags: r, violin-plot

I am trying to change the values in the x-axis of vioplot. I used a suggestion and wrote:

```
library(vioplot)  
labels=c(10,20,30)  
x1=c(1,2,3,4)  
x2=c(5,6,7,8,9,10)  
x3=c(11,12,13,14,15,16)  
x=list(x1,x2,x3)  
do.call(what = vioplot, args = x)  
axis(side=1,at=1:length(labels),labels=labels)
```

But it seems that the values in the a-axis are added to 1-2-3 which I don't want to be presented.

thank you

Comment: yes. but only if I can pass a list for the values in the violin and not specify each level seperatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your data in list() format, so it has to be converted to data frame. Then melt the data frame by stacking the values on top of each other.

Using `geom_violin` we create the kernel density plot and with `geom_boxplot`, we create boxplot on top of kernel density plot. The width of the boxplot is controlled using  `width`.

```
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')
df <- data.frame( lapply(x, function(y) {length(y) <- max(lengths(x)); y}))  # create data frame from list of x
colnames(df) <- as.character(labels)  # change column names to labels
df <- melt(df)                        # melt data frame
df <- df[ !is.na(df$value), ]         # remove NA
ggplot(data = df ) + 
  geom_violin(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable )) +   # kernel density plot
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = variable, y = value ), width = 0.1) +   # box plot
  xlab( " labels " ) +   # x axis title
  ylab( " values " )     # y axis title
```

[image]

**trim = FALSE**

```
ggplot(data = df ) + 
  geom_violin(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable ), trim = FALSE ) +   # kernel density plot
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = variable, y = value ), width = 0.1) +   # box plot
  xlab( " labels " ) +   # x axis title
  ylab( " values " )     # y axis title
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
labels=c(10,20,30)  
x1=c(1,2,3,4)  
x2=c(5,6,7,8,9,10)  
x3=c(11,12,13,14,15,16)  
x=list(x1,x2,x3)
```